# JQuery trigger insertBefore based on screen width and body class

Tags: jquery, width

I have created the following jQuery script which will move a div (#secondary) before another (#primary) should the screen width be equal to, or less than 767px and this works fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(screen.width<=767){
jQuery('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
}
});
```

However I would like the actual function to trigger on both the screen width and the body having a specific class (body.single). I have written the following but its not working, I think I am going wrong somewhere with the and statement, this is what I have so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(screen.width<=767) && ('body').hasClass('.single')    {
jQuery('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
}
});
```

I hope someone is able to explain where I have done wrong and how to rectify it. Thanks in advance to all

Comment: .hasClass('single') without dot  .. if(screen.width<=767 && $('body').hasClass('single')){

Answer (score 1):

**1st:** As a said in comment  `.hasClass('class without dot')`

**2nd:** `('body')` suppose to be `jQuery('body')`

**3rd:** with if statement use it like this

```
if(screen.width() <=767 && $('body').hasClass('.single')){
```

**Finally *your code should be***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if( screen.width() <= 767  && jQuery('body').hasClass('single')){
   jQuery('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/92cbhxLx/)

> **Note:** I don't know what you mean with screen or where you defined it but while you said **(and this works fine.)** my code should work
>   with you .. you can use `$(window).width()` instead of `screen.width()`in case if you need it

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if( $(window).width() <= 767  &&
  jQuery('body').hasClass('single')){
   jQuery('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="single">
  <div id="primary">Primary</div>
  <div id="secondary">Secondary</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed,

Thanks so much for your input, however I have followed your suggestions and it still does not work, I even tried to use $(window).width() as you suggested but it still will not work.
I know jQuery is not my strong point but I can not see why its not working?

Comment: @Paul it already works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/92cbhxLx/

Comment: Hi Mohamed in your jsfiddle you used addClass to assign 'single' to the body and it does work however, I have recreated it as it should be using jsfiddle (which I am new to) and it fails see here:- https://jsfiddle.net/9wwbqzhy/

Comment: @Paul it works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9wwbqzhy/1/ .. you forgot to include jquery .. in jsfiddle in top right gear on javascript section you need to choose jquery version you want .. and please always keep your eyes on console for errors .. screen is not define in your code there

Comment: @Paul and you need to use <body class="single"> instead of <body.single>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed, however no matter what I did I simply could not get the code to work, I have a number of other code snippets running as well and it could have been them that was causing the issue.

However I did find a solution and looking back it, I should have released it sooner. Instead of asking if the screen width was less than 767 AND if the body had class single, I merely needed to change the actual div being moved like so.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

if(screen.width<=767){

jQuery('body.single #secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
}

});
```

I hope this helps anyone else who has the same issue.

Thanks All